# How to grab arguments parsed to an command line application?

Tags: .net, command-line-arguments

I seem to be struggling with an issue of grabbing the input argument parsed in a solid way.

The application is only to accept input argument formated as such

```
program.exe --argumentA hello --argumentB Morningstar
```

where `--argumentA` is on of the keys and `hello` is the value.

All `args` are are parsed as an array of strings,

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

how do I make this able to handle, being able to provide the arguments in an arbitrary order?
and how do it extract them beside looking at the position in the `args` array, which don't secure for order provided is correct?

One solution I tried was just to change the main definition such that is would be

```
static async Task Main(string argumentA, string argumentB)
```

as this is what microsoft suggest being the easiest way to do it, but this then cause the application not to build since this main is not an valid entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a command line argument parser library. Example: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/command-line-parser-on-net5/

There are many others if you Google C# command line argument parser.